# How to fix 15-inch mid-2015 MacBook Pro overheating issue after Catalina upgrade?

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina

I upgraded my 15-inch Mid-2015 MacBook Pro to Catalina yesterday and, ever since, my fans won’t stop running.

Nothing abnormal in Activity Monitor and just opened it up and confirm it isn’t a dust issue.

I didn’t notice this before upgrading... Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Oddly enough I did this about a month ago with the exact same Mac. And for the first week I was *this close* to rolling back to Mojave. But the system settled down and it is much better now. I am thinking there is a lot of Spotlight going on in the background along with a bunch of other basic maintenance going on as well, optimizing the system for your usage habits. Granted it IS more prone to getting a bit warm from video filled web pages than previously but that is acceptable, after the first week that is...

Comment: @SteveChambers Interesting... for privacy reasons, I disabled Siri and Spotlight. Hope my system settles too.